# Laravel one to many relationship | Undefined offset | on Update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, relation

I have two models `Post` and `Author` in my project

> Post => `return $this->hasMany('App\Author')`
>
> Author => `return $this->belongsTo('App\Post')`

Currently i have one record in `Post` and two in `Author`, Now i am removing one record from the list and saving it and it gives me exception.

> Undefined offset: 1

Following is the code :

```
    $post = \App\Post::with('authors')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $post->user_id = Auth()->user()->id;
    $post->name = $request->name;
    foreach ($post->authors as $key => $author) {
        $author->post_id = $post->id;
        $author->life_span = $request->life_span[$key];
        $author->duration = $request->duration[$key];
        $author->save();
    }
    $post->save();
```

Comment: 1 post can have several authors?

Comment: @iwex yes one post have several  authors.

Comment: Actually what you are trying to do? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @NIKhilnediyodath I am simply trying to update relational records of a record means i am updating authors of the post, I can do that for one author for a post but can't do it for two or more.

Comment: Check whether the `$key` (1) exist in `life_span` and `duration`

Comment: 1 author is belongs to a post!? Can you share you database structure of `authors` and `posts` table?

Comment: authors it's possible to have one or more post?
if response is at yes, I don't understand your database structure,  if post have many authors and authors have many post. this relation is many-to-many not many to one. Because one authors is only possible in one post. and many post lost authors reference in future if this author generate other post. Only registre one post on authors model.
Sorry if you don't understand me, my english is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you are trying to do with this foreach but add an `if` check

```
foreach ($post->authors as $key => $author) {
    $author->post_id = $post->id;
    if(isset($request->life_span[$key]) && isset($request->duration[$key])) {
      $author->life_span = $request->life_span[$key];
      $author->duration = $request->duration[$key];
    }
    $author->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

It means an array doesn't have an index or key.

Please check

> $request->life_span[$key];

does it exist? Probably you miss that.